# Looping through file 001 to 909 in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

Suppose I have one python script which takes in two arguments:

```
python3 a.py '/001/001.txt' '/after/001'
```

'/001/001.txt' would be the input file path, '/after/001' would be the output path, I would like to know how can I set the input_path and output_path in the following bash commands to loop automatically through file 001 to 909.

```
i=1; 
while [ $i -le 909 ]; 
do 
    input_path = ''
    output_path = '';
    python3 a.py $input_path $output_path
 
    i=$((i+1)); 
done
```

I am first time using bash commands, so can anyone share how to solve this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: `input_path=$(printf "/%03d/%03d.txt" "$i" "$i")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` version >= 4.0:

```
for i in {001..909}; do
  echo python3 a.py "/$i/$i.txt" "/after/$i"
done
```

With `bash` version >= 3.1:

```
for ((i=1; i<=909; i++)); do
  printf -v x "%03d" "$i"
  echo python3 a.py "/$x/$x.txt" "/after/$x"
done
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: for bash-3 it could be `for i in $(printf '%03d\n' {1..909}); do ...`